# Prevent Xdebug from formatting PHP error messages

Tags: php, xdebug

I am using Xdebug only for IDE debugging and would like to stop it from reformatting error messages thrown by PHP in the browser. I just want regular PHP error message, without stack trace, table layouts or anything else. How do I achieve that?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In this case, you want to set: `xdebug.default_enable=0`. This will disable the stack traces upon error message.

Comment: This removed table borders etc. from the error message. But still, error is being concatenated

Answer (score 2):

You can control XDebug's stack trace in php.ini:

See http://xdebug.org/docs/stack_trace

For full config options: http://xdebug.org/docs/all_settings

Answer (score 2):

This code will fix the issue **without need to change your xdebug configuration**.
https://xdebug.org/docs/all_functions

```
if (function_exists('xdebug_disable')) {
    //Disables stack traces
    //Disable showing stack traces on error conditions.
    xdebug_disable();
}
```

Setting `xdebug.default_enable=0` as suggested by Derick works well but requires change of xdebug settings.

You might want to register your own error handler using `register_shutdown_function()`

I have found following issues when xdebug stack traces are enabled:

1. Response code is always 200 and you can't override that
2. In case you are working on something like API which is expected to respond with formatted error message (JSON error response for example) this would make the response malformed, because xdebug will output before you can output using your own registered shutdown function

Interestingly enough when `xdebug.default_enable=0` is not specified in your xdebug configuration then `ini_get('xdebug.default_enable')` will return string "0". If you set `xdebug.default_enable=0` it is also string "0". Therefore you can't use `ini_get('xdebug.default_enable')` to detect wheteher it is enabled or not.

Comment: Note that `xdebug_disable()` has been [removed](https://xdebug.org/docs/upgrade_guide) in Xdebug 3. **There is no longer any way to disable Xdebug-formatted messages during runtime.**